My Spark job on EMR is stuck for large datasets. The driver is waiting for executer signal but executer has completed its task & waiting for next task
I am new to Spark and EMR on EKS. I am getting data from MongoDB collection. The job is running on local machine(without cluster mode) for both large and small datasets and is working for datasets with 300k rows on EKS cluster, but when I use larger datasets like in 70M+ the driver is waiting for executor's signal but executor is waiting for next task after a task completion happens every time, what configuration am I missing?
I tried tuning the parallelisms, partitions and network timeout.
These are the configurations I have kept during job deployment:
spark_submit_cmd = [
        "--deploy-mode",
        "cluster",
        "--packages",
        "org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.12:3.0.1,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:3.3.4,",  # noqa
        "--conf",
        f"spark.kubernetes.container.image={cfg('spark.docker.image')}",
        "--conf",
        "spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true",
        "--conf",
        "spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors=2",
        "--conf",
        "spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors=5",
        "--conf",
        "spark.executor.memory=2g",
        "--conf",
        "spark.executor.cores=1",
        "--conf",
        f"spark.kubernetes.driver.podTemplateFile=s3://grepsr-aws-emr{'-stg' if os.getenv('APP_ENV')=='stg' else ''}/pod-template/spark-template.yaml",  # noqa
        "--conf",
        f"spark.kubernetes.executor.podTemplateFile=s3://grepsr-aws-emr{'-stg' if os.getenv('APP_ENV')=='stg' else ''}/pod-template/spark-template.yaml",  # noqa
        # "--conf",
        # "spark.kubernetes.executor.annotation.scheduler.alpha.kubernetes.io/tolerations=[{'key': 'role', 'operator': 'Equal', 'value': 'spark', 'effect': 'NoSchedule'}]" # noqa
        "--conf",
        "spark.driver.memory=8g",
        "--conf",
        "spark.driver.cores=1",
        "--conf",
        "spark.network.timeout=60s",
        "--conf",
        "spark.executor.heartbeatInterval=5s",
        "--conf",
        "spark.default.parallelism=100",
        "--conf",
        "spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=1000",
    ]


    for item in env_vars_items.keys():
        spark_submit_cmd.append("--conf")
        spark_submit_cmd.append(f"spark.kubernetes.driverEnv.CFG_{item.upper()}={env_vars_items[item]}")
        spark_submit_cmd.append("--conf")
        spark_submit_cmd.append(f"spark.executorEnv.CFG_{item.upper()}={env_vars_items[item]}")
        spark_submit_cmd.append("--conf")
        spark_submit_cmd.append(f"spark.kubernetes.executorEnv.CFG_{item.upper()}={env_vars_items[item]}")

            SparkSession.builder.appName(self.app_name)
            # .config("spark.master", os.getenv("CFG_SPARK_MASTER_HOST"))
            .config(
                "spark.mongodb.input.uri",
                os.getenv("CFG_SPARK_MONGO_URI"),
            )
            .config("spark.mongodb.input.database", os.getenv("CFG_MONGO_DB"))
            .config("spark.mongodb.input.collection", self.mongo_collection)
            .config(
                "spark.jars.packages",
                "org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.12:3.0.1,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:3.3.4,",
            )
            .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.access.key", os.getenv("CFG_AWS_ACCESS_KEY"))
            .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.secret.key", os.getenv("CFG_AWS_SECRET_KEY"))
            .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.endpoint", os.getenv("CFG_AWS_S3_ENDPOINT"))
            .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.region", "eu-central-1")
            .config(
                "spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.SimpleAWSCredentialsProvider"
            )
            .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem")
            .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.path.style.access", "true")
            # .config(
            #     "spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.block.size",
            #     os.getenv("CFG_AWS_S3_BLOCK_SIZE"),
            # )
            # .config(
            #     "spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.multipart.size",
            #     os.getenv("CFG_AWS_S3_MULTIPART_SIZE"),
            # )
            # .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.committer.name", "/commits")
            # .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.fast.upload", "true")
            # .config("spark.sql.sources.commitProtocolClass", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.commit.staging.S3ACommitterFactory") # noqa
            # .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.committer.staging.conflict-mode", "replace")
            .getOrCreate()

I tried tuning parallelisms, partitions, network timeout and specs of executor and driver by some GB.

Is the task failing or is it just slow? What do you want to achieve / what is the issue?

It is not failing, its just slow while streaming from mongo, if i use avro files from s3 it is way fast.
